# An differential equation$(x^{2}＋y^{2}＋3)\frac{dy}{dx}＝2x(2y-\frac{x^{2}}{y})$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this ODE $$(x^{2}＋y^{2}＋3)\frac{dy}{dx}＝2x(2y-\frac{x^{2}}{y})$$
I tried to find its integral factor, but failed.
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have an initial condition? With that, there's at least a possibility of a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $t=x^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{dy}{dt}\dfrac{dt}{dx}=2x\dfrac{dy}{dt}$

$\therefore(x^2+y^2+3)2x\dfrac{dy}{dt}=2x\left(2y-\dfrac{x^2}{y}\right)$

$(x^2+y^2+3)\dfrac{dy}{dt}=2y-\dfrac{x^2}{y}$

$(t+y^2+3)\dfrac{dy}{dt}=2y-\dfrac{t}{y}$

Let $u=y^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dt}=2y\dfrac{dy}{dt}$

$\therefore\dfrac{t+y^2+3}{2y}\dfrac{du}{dt}=2y-\dfrac{t}{y}$

$(t+y^2+3)\dfrac{du}{dt}=4y^2-2t$

$(t+u+3)\dfrac{du}{dt}=4u-2t$

Comment: Next? What I should do?I still do not know how to deal with it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: next pl. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation#Special_case   Alpha and beta can be found as solution of two linear equations

Answer (score 0):

$(y^2+x^2+3)(y^2)'=4x(2y^2-x^2)$

$(y^2+x^2+3)(y^2+x^2+3)'=4x(2y^2-x^2)+2x(y^2+x^2+3)$

$(y^2+x^2+3)(y^2+x^2+3)'=10x(y^2+x^2+3)-4x(3x^2+6)$

With $\enspace z:=y^2+x^2+3\enspace$ we get $\enspace zz'=10xz-12x^3-24x$ .

I don't know how to solve this, but Wolfram solves it in a closed form with

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z(dz%2Fdx)%3D10xz-12x%5E3-24x .